# How to make Array Items Hyperlink in HTML using PHP(Code Ignitor)

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I'm trying to display a list of Meter Serial Number using Array, and when I click on any item of that array I want to display a new page and Meter Serial Number on which I clicked should carry to new page so that I can display information regarding to that serial number, here is my code to display the list which is working fine:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table  class="table table-bordered table-hover 
workorder-table">
<thead>
<!-- <th>Devices with data = <?php echo " 
".count($devices_with_data); ?></th> -->
<th>Meter Serial Number </th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach($meterSerialNumber as $serial){ ?>
<tr>
<td> <?php echo $serial ?> </td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>

</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

All I want the code or trick to display new page with that serial number, I am new to web development so expecting little help here.

Comment: Can you show your controller

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp - maybe this helps

Answer (score 0):

Use [anchor helper](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#anchor) function and pass serial number

```
<td><?php echo anchor('controller/function/'.$serial, 'Serial number') ?>
```

Comment: here is controller:
$page_data['allDevices'] = $allDevices;

$page_data['devices_with_data'] = $deviceWithDataArr;

$deviceswithNoData = array_diff($allDevices, $deviceWithDataArr);
 $deviceswithNoLongData = array_diff($deviceWithMeterSerialNumber,$devicesWithLongDataArr);

$page_data['time'] = $time;

$page_data['devices_with_no_data'] = $deviceswithNoData;

$page_data['devices_with_no_long_data'] = $deviceswithNoLongData;

$page_data['meterSerialNumber'] = $deviceWithMeterSerialNumber;

$page_data['region'] = $region;

$this->load->view('all_devices', $page_data);